# System cannot find file while connecting database in nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using fluent nhibernate since long. Its working fine until I updated my database. Prior I was using SQL Server 2012, and updated it to 2016. When try to connect database in application, it throws an error:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

when it tried to connect. My connecting function is as below

```
    Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ShowSql().ConnectionString(x=> x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("imConnectionString2"))).Mappings(m=> m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MapUsers>()).BuildSessionFactory();
```

This was working fine before database update. I change `MsSql2005` it to `MsSql2012`, but same result.

Do I have to do anything in Fluent Nhibernate side or configuration?

Any assistance please

Comment: Add full exception info.

Comment: Can you feedback if you resolved the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it didn't work for me, so i reverted back to use old server

Answer (score 0):

There is a major change in the client connectivity for SQL Server 2016.
This change is due to sql client is becoming support windows and other O.S like Linux.

install [Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server - Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420)
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420

review: [Installing SQL Server Native Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131321.aspx)

*SQL Server Native Client (SNAC) is not supported beyond SQL Server 2012. Avoid using SNAC in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. The Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server provides native connectivity from Windows to Microsoft SQL Server*

Before configuring Nhibernate, be sure that you can connect with SQL server 2016 by using sqlcmd tool (for server 2016- download it)

**Update:**

When you install the driver named msodbcsql.msi, it's really the same driver of sql 2012 client.

I installed the driver in windows 7 (32 bit), using the library FluentNHibernate v 2.0.3 and connecting to SQL server 2016 and running successfully the following code:

```
class FluentNHibernateTest
{
    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
       //also MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005 is working
        return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(
                    MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ShowSql()
                        .ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("test16")))
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
                .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    public static string GetSqlVersion()
    {
        string sql = "select @@version version";
        var sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            var query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql);
            var result = query.UniqueResult();
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Output result:

```
     FluentNHibernateTest.GetSqlVersion();

  Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-CU1) (KB3164674) - 13.0.2149.0 (X64)
    Jul 11 2016 22:05:22
    .......
```